# Issue where I can't import ts files in vscode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

[image]I tried renaming the file extension of JavaScript files to .ts in my project and attempted to import them, but they still appear as JavaScript files instead of TypeScript files in VSCode. Even after reinstalling VSCode, the issue persists. However, when I import the same project in IntelliJ, this problem does not occur.

I have considered the possibility of a cache issue in VSCode and have tried rebooting, as well as moving the branch to another computer to run it. However, the same problem still persists.

Comment: When you use ESM with typescript, you are importing the target file with the .js extension. This is by design (and yes a little ugly)

Comment: weird. maybe a "caching" issue? What if you run `TypeScript: Restart TS Server` or `TypeScript: Reload Project` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)?